# file get contents extracting certain parts?

Tags: php, html, xml, file-get-contents

I have an xml document that is generated based on what the parametres are in the URL

for example:

```
menu.php?category=clothing
```

This will generate an xml page.

Now I want to display this in a formatted way on the menu, after having a look it seems that:

file_get_contents() seems to be the best option.

But I was just wondering how I can place elements and attributes found in this xml into the html code?

Any tips/help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use [PHP's SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

[Tutorial on SimpleXML](http://debuggable.com/posts/parsing-xml-using-simplexml:480f4dfe-6a58-4a17-a133-455acbdd56cb)

---

Simple load as a string or a file:

```
$source = 'mydata.xml';

// load as string
$xmlstr = file_get_contents($source);
$parseXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
print($parseXML);

// load as file
$parseXMLFile = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);

print_r($parseXMLFile);
```

---

Let's say this is your xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
 </movie>
</movies>
```

Doing this would give you the title:

```
$parseXMLFile = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);
echo $parseXMLFile->movie[0]->title;
```

Comment: What about including elements of this specific xml page in different parts of the HTML code?

Comment: you can echo the html out along w/ the data you load from the XML file.

Comment: @Xerting actually, i am not sure what you mean by 'different parts of the HTML code' can you please give an example.

Comment: I mean placing certain parts of the XML within the HTML page. E.g

placing it within a specific div so it is displayed and correctly styled.

Comment: @Xerting sounds like you are looking to do a JavaScript ajax call.  one way to do that is to have a php script that reads in the xml file and echo out the html that you wish to display based on a GET/POST request (of course the php would have to be able to receive GET/POST request), and using JavaScript to do an ajax call and insert into the appropriate div.

Comment: Not sure.. 

Basically, when I click a button a range of parametres is sent and an XML document is returned based on those parameters. I need to place elements within this XML page into a PHP page.

I can't see how this is possible without showing the user the raw XML.

Comment: @Xerting take a look at this article.  This article talks about simple ajax call and how it interacts w/ php http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript

Comment: Hmm I've had a read and I am not sure that it is what I'm after. I'm not looking for things to be changing on a single page. The user is clicking through to another page and it is that page that needs to get populated based on the content of that XML generatation.

Comment: @Xerting then you can basically echo out the html content of that page using php. IE: `echo "<html><head></head><body><div id='content'> $parseXMLFile->movie[0]->title </div></body></html>";` or something similar

Comment: Seriously, do you not have to put that "$parseXMLFile->movie[0]->title" with the php tags <?

Comment: @Xerting yes,`echo...` should be inside `<?php ... ?>` tag.  the code i submit as answer should all be within `<?php>` tag because they are PHP